# Routing / Unknown action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a route pointing to a method in controller like:

```
match foo/bar => bar#qux
```

When I have an instance method called `qux`, it seems to be finding the controller alright, because it (correctly, I think) complains that there's no such method (because it's supposed to be static).

When I have a static method `self.qux` in bar, however, it tells me:

```
Unknown action

The action 'qux' could not be found for Bar
```

Comment: Controller actions should *not* be class methods; that would make that whole "exposing action instance variables" kind of fall to pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller's actions must be instances methods. Rails will spawn an instance of your controller and attempt to invoke the given method on it.

`def self.qux` should simply be `def qux`.